# The set of almost-homomorphisms is closed under composition.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

We call a function $f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ an almost-homomorphism if
$|f(m + n) - f(m) - f(n)| \le C$ for some $C \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$.
I am trying to show that the composition $f \circ g$ of two almost-homomorphisms $f, g$ is again an almost-homomorphism. So far I have been able to reach:

$$|f(g(m+n)) - f(g(m)) - f(g(n))| = |f(g(m+n)) - f(g(m) + g(n)) + f(g(m) + g(n)) - f(g(m)) - f(g(n))|$$
$$ \le |f(g(m+n)) - f(g(m) + g(n))| + C_f$$

with $C_f$ the bound on $|f(m + n) - f(m) - f(n)|$.

p.s: I know that this is provable by considering the finite sets $\{f(m + n) - f(m) - f(n) | m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\{g(m + n) - g(m) - g(n) | m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, and showing that $f(g(m+n)) - f(g(m)) - f(g(n))$ takes on only finitely many different values, which is how the proof works for almost-homomorphisms defined on arbitrary rings (where an almost homomorphism is directly defined via this set being finite). However, technically it should also be possible to prove it by just using inequalities, right?

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note: Using $|f(n+1)-f(n)-f(1)|\le C_f$, we find by induction that there are $A_f=C_f+\max\{|f(1)|,|f(-1)|\}$ such that $|f(n)|\le A_f|n|+C_f$.

We have
$$\begin{align}|f(g(m+n))-f(g(m)-f(g(n))|&
\le|f(g(m+n))-f(g(m)+g(n))|\\&\quad + |f(g(m)+g(n))-f(g(m)-f(g(n))|\\
&\le C_f + |f(g(m+n))-f(g(m)+g(n))|\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
|f(g(m+n))-f(g(m)+g(n))|
&\le |f(g(m+n))-f(g(m)+g(n))-f(g(m+n)-g(m)-g(n))|\\&\quad+|f(g(m+n)-g(m)-g(n))|\\
&\le C_f+|f(g(m+n)-g(m)-g(n))|\\
&\le 2C_f+A_fC_g.\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is great! Thank you!

Comment: Could you maybe explain a bit how we prove the first note? Do we also assume that $f$ is an odd function? (if not what do we do induction on?)

EDIT: After working on it for a while, I figured out the induction principle. It is also now clear to me why we have $\max \{|f(1)|, |f(-1)|\}$. Thank you again!